# Writing a function which will allow users to enroll on a course

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

I am developing a site for an assignment using only html, css and php. The site allows users to register and login, once logged in they can view a list of courses and enroll on ones which they wish. I am currently trying to write a function which will allow users to enroll on a course but I am having trouble.

The tables in my database look like this:

user:

```
user_id     username      password     name
```

section:

```
section_id     title      level     description
```

user-section:

```
user_id     section_id
```

When a user presses the 'enroll' button an a chosen course page I want a function to run which will have an insert query which will pair the user_id with the section_id

This is the function I currently have:

```
function enroll($conn,$section_id,$user_id){

$query="INSERT INTO user-section VALUES (:user_id, :section-id)";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);
$stmt->bindValue(':section_id', $section_id);
$affected_rows = $stmt->execute();
if($affected_rows==1)
{
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Using this I am getting errors regarding undefined variables section_id and user_id. How can I change this to get my function working? Thanks.

edit: The site is being made as an MVC framework.

The pages involved look like this:

section-details.php

```
<?php
include ("helpers/db_fncs.php"); //connect to db
include ("models/section-model.php");
$conn=getConn();
$checkLogin=checkLogin($conn);
if(isset($_GET['section_id']))
{
    $section_id = $_GET['section_id'];
    $section=getSectionById($conn,$section_id);
    $conn=NULL;
    if($section)
    {
        include("views/section-details-view.php");
    }else{
        include("views/error-view.php");
    }
}else{
    include("views/error-view.php");
}

?>
```

section-details-view.php

```
<?php
include ("view_fncs.php");
showHeader();
showNavigation("Course Details");

echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>Course: ".$section->title."</li>";
echo "<li>Level: ".$section->level."</li>";
echo "<li>Description: ".$section->description."</li>";
echo "</ul>";
?>

<form action='enroll-process.php' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name'enroll' value='Enroll on Course'>
</form>

<?php
showFooter();

?>
```

enroll-process.php

```
<?php
include ("helpers/db_fncs.php");
include ("models/section-model.php");
$conn=getConn();
$enroll=enroll($conn,$section_id,$user_id);
$conn=NULL;
?>
```

Comment: How are you setting those variables? Are you using a form? Can you post that form here?

Comment: In `enroll-process.php` you call `enroll($conn,$section_id,$user_id);`, though `$section_id` and `$user_id` are not defined in that file. If they are also not defined in `helpers/db_fncs.php` or `models/section-model.php`, then the error is not in the function but in the **call** to the function. (Side note, include/require are *statements*, not *functions*, use `include "helpers/db_fncs.php";`)

Comment: @jay @Yoshi How would I define those variables?  `helpers/db_fncs.php` just allows the page to connect to the database, `models/section-model.php` is full of different functions used throughout the site

Comment: @Sam I have a feeling that this is completely out of scope for this question... When you defined `enroll(...)` where did you except those values to come from?